# javascript:how to prevent default exitFullscreen event?

Tags: javascript

I find I can't understand this mechanism.

I use `event.preventDefault()` but `exitFullscreen` occurs before this event captured by me.

For example, I press `F11`, the window recover before the event that bound to `F11` activating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, this should not be possible, since the user always has the ability to exit fullscreen mode at any time.

While the [official spec](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/) makes no mention of the cancellability of the fullscreenschange event, this behavior is clearly detailed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

Comment: I have read it and couldn't find the useful information for me.I just want to do something and then exit full screen.So now I can do nothing but only edit this exitFullscreen() provided by browser?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to prevent the user from exiting from fullscreen.  Correct?

Comment: No,I just want to make code more modeling-like.And I'm curious about this api.

Comment: You should have no issue entering and exiting fullscreen programatically , as explained here:  https://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen.  If that's not what you're looking for, then please explain what you mean by 'make code more modeling-like'.

Comment: I firstly think that the exiting full screen  function like example can not be changed because they are all same,and I want to make a function only do one thing with nice structure which I mean modeling-like.Now I  got it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent exiting fullscreen mode. It would be a security issue if a website could prevent a user from closing it.